# ¿Cómo puedo desactivar el Dark Theme por defecto que implementan los dispositivos Xiaomi en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, aplicación-movil

Estoy teniendo problemas con los dispositivos **Xiaomi** que tienen el **DarkTheme** en su Android al instalar mi app.

Al instalar mi app, que no tiene DarkTheme en un dispositivo Xiaomi, el genera por defecto un DarkTheme en mi aplicación y se ve así:
[Visualizar imagen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3OSC.png) y [Visualizar imagen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMINz.png)

Como podéis ver, me cambia los colores de los TextView, los Cardview me los pinta en negro, cuando son blancos por defecto, los textos de las Cardview los pone en un color rosa cuando por defecto son de otro color..

He probado con otros dispositivos Samsung, Huawei.. Los únicos que me generan este conflicto son los Xiaomi. Buscando en las configuraciones del teléfono vi lo siguiente: [Visualizar imagen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haq9K.png)

Parece ser que viene activada por defecto una opción en esta pantalla que hace que el sistema operativo genere el DarkTheme el solo, otras aplicaciones lo tienen desactivado por defecto.

**¿Hay alguna manera para que yo también lo pueda hacer por código en mi app?**

He estado buscando diferentes soluciones pero no lo he conseguido. La que mas he leído es poniendo esto, pero no me ha funcionado:

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

Comment: Has creado un theme único para tu aplicación que machaque eso, normalmente cuando creas un theme y se lo pones al manifest siempre lee tu theme ahora si la app no le configuras ningún theme cogerá el predeterminado del móvil.

Comment: ¿Y como puedo hacer para solucionar este problema que tengo?

Comment: Aqui en la documentación de Android veras como realizarlo por si me he explicado mal: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo deberías de crear un `styles.xml` en `res/values/styles.xml`
En el archivo `styles.xml` pondrías lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
     <style name="GreenText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
         <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
         ...
     </style>
    </resources>
```

Esto lo que haces es que deriva del `TextAppearance.AppCompat` que es el tema oscuro y sobre escribes el tema con los `item`.

Después para aplicar dicho estilo en toda la aplicación en el manifest haces lo siguiente:

```
<manifest ... >
    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" ... >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

O si lo que necesitas es aplicarlo a la Actividad porque la aplicación solamente tiene una seria así:

```
<manifest ... >
<application ... >
    <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

De esta manera crearias un tema tuio sobrescribiendo el predeterminado con tus estilos.

Comment: Buenas! He probado lo que me acabas de comentar, y nada me sigue pintando el sistema operativo de Xiaomi su propio DarkTheme en mi aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes solucionarlo, al menos a mi me sirve así, declarando la siguiente propiedad en tu `onCreate` de la actividad:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Lo que puedes hacer también es añadir en tu `style.xml` justo donde tienes el `AppTheme` de tu aplicación algo como esto:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
</style>
```